# file_get_contents weird encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I am using file_get_contents to retrieve and save the html of some websites. I don't know what encoding each site might have.

I am using the following which works for the majority of sites:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($html);

if($encoding != 'UTF-8') {
   $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", $encoding); 
}
```

This generally works, but there are a couple of sites that returns something like this:

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 ed7d eb72 db46
b6ee efb8 6ade a1c3 a98a a43d 0489 fb45
b6e4 7194 4ce2 d976 e21d 799c 3367 9272
```

About 1000 rows of this junk. 
What is it and how do I fix it so that it will return the HTML of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but, sometimes `mb_detect_encoding` fails to detect char encoding and returns false. You could see if that's the case with these couple of sites.

Comment: Can you give any URL of site, which returns wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for your requirements.
For example:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTMLFile($url);
$html->saveHTMLFile('your_file_name');
```